# are tamper resistant receptacles required when rewiring an old house

Tags: wiring, nec

rewiring an old house due to having knob and tube wiring.  it it code to have all receptacles tamper resistant?  Does the NEC require hard wired smoke and carbon monoxide detectors?  Are "in-use" cover plates required on outside gfci outlets?

Comment: Are you changing the receptacles?  Also on the circuits going outside, are there any indoor receptacles or junction boxes om the same circuit and before the outdoor outlets? (Best to not put GFCIs outdoors if avoidable)

Comment: yes, all of the receptacles will have to be changes to put boxes in where needed.  yes there are inside receptacles and junction boxes on the same circuit.  The outdoor outlets were already installed we just changed them to GFCI's.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use TR receptacles in any case. Here in Tennessee, if I were to pull a permit to do this, yes my jurisdiction wants permits for anything and everything electrical, I would most definitely have to use TR outlets. They aren't much more in expense compared to a standard receptacle.

It's not overkill and I personally would prefer to err towards safety and/or over protection. This will also prevent any issues down the road as far as codes are concerned.

Edit: (Brain fart)

Not sure about carbon monoxide detectors, but hardwired smokes are required.

As for your outdoor receptacles, they do need weatherproof covers but the type of cover will depend on location. Weatherproof ( bubble ) covers should be used if a receptacle is located where there's no overhead protection or if a receptacle is installed, say on a covered porch, but the receptacle is 3' or less away from the edge of the covering roof.

Comment: I agree depending on the type of receptacle. In some cases old knob tube upgrades with polarized 2 pin outlets are still legal ( I don't know of any 2 pin outlets that are are tamper resistant). So it depends on where you are and what the AHJ requires.+

Comment: @EdBeal The OP is rewiring because of having K&T...